# Greys "Aliens" mentioned in Kabala?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, natural-phenomenon, sheidim-demons

I have heard and even read (in Rav Zamir Cohen's book The Coming Revolution) that the most well known Alien phenotype, the "Greys" (who have large heads, large dark eyes, slits for noses, and very skinny body frames) are in fact mentioned with the same defining features in the literature of Kabala, and they are described as demons who inhabit the inner earth. Is it true that Kabala talks about such a thing, and if so where? I have heard this claim for several years, and I always wonder if it's true

Comment: Doesn't the book you mention provide that information (of where Kabala talks about the "Greys" being demons who inhabit the inner earth)? How does it substantiate it's claim?

Comment: just fyi there is a lot that goes around in the name of kabala that isn't true, the thing about kabala is that it is mysterious to the majority of people and kabalistic works are widely untranslated, and even with translation or understanding what the words mean much is lost or not completely understood

Comment: @ezra Exactly, thats why im asking this. I wanted to know if its true or not

Comment: (1) Zamir Cohen's book is largely pseudo-science. (2) There is no evidence for ancient aliens, let alone the notion that ancient aliens reside underground!

Comment: @turk never said i believe in aliens, but thats not an argument. Also, that's Rav Zamir Cohen to you. Not sure why you think it's so-called "psedo-science" as if science means anything or is static

Comment: @KapinKrunch Most of Rav Cohen's book espouses on pseudo-science. Views that the modern scientific community rejects. For example, the existence of aliens or that the world plate tectonics split during the events of the flood four thousand years ago. In short, he twists science like a pretzel to fit his mystical world-view. After reading his first volume, I don't recommend his book.

Comment: I dont see how that's "Mystical" (what's wrong with that anyways) ? using the term Pseudo-science is very subjective. The soul is also considered "pseudo-science" by scientists today. And so is aether

Comment: In the sefer פתח עינים on menachot 83 page 111 he writes that there are subterrestrial humanoid creatures that have two heads.

Comment: Thank you @Shababnik

Comment: @KapinKrunch you're welcome.  Not sure if that's what you're looking for but it's the closest concept that I know of.